# Grammatical analysis of comparative parts (i.e. "tam … quam", etc.)

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-identification, adverb, comparative, seneca-iunior

I have the following sentence from Seneca, epistula 1, §2:
*"Cum placuerit fieri, toto illum pectore admitte; tam audaciter cum illo loquere quam tecum."*
However, I'm not sure what the *"tam audaciter cum illo quam tecum"*-part is? An adverbial adjunct? 
Likewise, this sentence: *"Sed si aliquem amicum existimas cui non tantundem credis quantum tibi, vehementer erras et non satis nosti vim verae amicitiae."* What is *"tantundem quantum tibi"*?

Answer (score 2):

It's adverbial in both cases. The demonstrative adjective-modifier(?) *tam* modifies the adverb *audaciter*, which is the core of the adverbial phrase expressing how you should talk with people; and *quam...* is another—parallel—adverbial phrase, an adverbial subordinate clause.

*Tantundem* is an adverb to *credis*, expressing the extent of your trusting someone, and the *quantum...* clause is parallel.

Note that *tecum* and *tibi* are inside the subordinate *quam* and *quantum* clauses, respectively, so they have direct conexion to the main clauses.